# Can i use one laptop to charge another laptop by connecting the two together with a usb cable?

Tags: laptop, charging, power-jack

My Toshiba laptop has a problem with the ac charging adapter.  The problem is with the computer and not the charging cord.  The geek squad told me that Toshiba laptops have had the same problem in the past.  I dont want to spend $400 dollars to fix it or buy a new one.  Please let me know if anyone knows a way to charge my computer.  Thank you and please give me good news!!

Comment: To answer your USB question, NO.

Comment: There are many companies that do "DC jack repair" Google it.

Comment: @Moab: Or the power circuit is broken...

Comment: There was a question similar to this about charging via USB: http://superuser.com/questions/158398/charge-a-laptop-via-usb-power-500ma

Answer (score 3):

You might try a docking station. The docking station will charge the battery via a different connector (underneath the laptop). It will add some weight but could be less expensive than a repair/replacement.

Note: It is not only a loose power connector that can cause a charging failure. It can also be the power circuitry on the system board, which cannot usually be repaired except by replacing the board (a familiar problem with Dells; I don't know about Toshibas).

Having said that, I'd take it to an independent repair shop (definitely not geek squad), it may be a $50 fix if it is a loose connector.

Answer (score 2):

What they were referring to is that the jack lifted off the board and needs to be soldered back on. Unfortunately if you ever want to charge it again, you'll need to have that repaired. HP and Compaq computers are also well known for this type of issue.

Answer (score 2):

Over USB? No. The voltage is too low, it would take ages, and it simply won't work as you will blow up your laptop if you *do* find a way to do it.
Put your laptop battery in another laptop, charge it, put it back.
Only make sure that the battery's got the same voltage as the original battery of the laptop you place it in to charge. If ti doesn't fit, don't force it, better not take the risk to also screw up the other laptop.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get charging working again you could as well just replace the power connector instead. Unless your power circuit is broke, in which case the USB charging isn't going work either...